# Use data-popup attributes to show Jquery-ui dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

The JS snippet below should show only the requests popups which has the same ID as its trigger.

For example `<a class="popup-button" data-popup="#popup-a">POPUP A</a>` should show popup that has the ID `#popup-a` when click on.

But when clicked on any of the triggers, it shows all popups that are on the page instead from the popup that is requested "has the same ID that the trigger has it its attribute", here is a **JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/znq4jwdu/1/**

```
//Popups
$('.popup-button').each(function() { 
    var popupId = $(this).attr("data-popup");
    $.data(this, 'dialog', $(popupId).dialog({
    modal: false,
   open: function(){
        $(".dialog").addClass("dialog-opened");
        $('.popup-close').fadeIn();
        $('#falseModal').fadeIn();
        jQuery('#falseModal').bind('click',function(){
            jQuery('.popup').dialog('close');
    });
    },
    close: function(){
        $(".dialog").removeClass("dialog-opened");
        $('#falseModal').fadeOut();
    }
}));  
}).click(function() {  
    $.data(this, 'dialog').dialog('open');  
    return false;  
});
$('.popup-close').each(function() {  
    $(this).on("click",function(){$(this).parents('.popup').dialog("close");});  
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    $(".popup").dialog("option", "position", {my: "center", at: "center", of: window});
    $('.widget-overlay').show().fadeOut(800);
});
$("body").append('<div id="falseModal" style="display:none;"></div>');
```

Comment: what is the false model for?

Comment: It is for the overlap div, the div that overlaps the content behind the pop-up. I needed to fade in and out, so I had to add an extra div and call it falseModal.

Comment: so its only to create an overlay effect?

Comment: Yes, only to create an overlay effect

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use .each since you already have a class (.popup) for the dialog containers.

Just hide them on load using `autoOpen`.

And open them by `dialog('open')`. For the overlay effect make give it a `modal: true`.

For transition effect use the show and hide effect options along with duration.

```
$('.popup').dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
        effect: 'fade',
        duration: 500
    },
    hide: {
        effect: 'fade',
        duration: 500
    },
    open: function () {

    },
    close: function () {

    }
});
$('.popup-button').on('click', function () {
    var popupId = $(this).attr("data-popup");
    $(popupId).dialog('open');
});
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/odLrrn17/2/**

Also, in  your demo you had reversed data-popup references.

Comment: This works on JsFiddle but it does not on my site, same code, what do you think it might be? Only the overlay shows but not the popup

Comment: that's weird. Can you provide other code that *might* interfere with the popups ?

Comment: in your core.css you have `opacity:0` for `.dialog{}`. This is one of the problems. Still looking at other ones

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81014/discussion-between-leo-and-dhiraj-bodicherla).

Comment: you don't need `visibility: hidden;` and `opacity:0`. That is causing the problem. Also, load all your scrips after all the elements i.e before the body ends. That should make it work